# How to refresh custom title of event in fullcalendar.io

Tags: angular, fullcalendar

I am using fullcalendar events with extendedProps named

- public (boolean)
- external (boolean)
- gema (boolean)
- security (boolean)

Those extendedProps are displayed in the event title as strings, that shows up like:

Title => "Testevent (öffentlich, extern)"

I achieve this custom title like this:

Component:

```
export class EventListComponent {

  calendarOptions: CalendarOptions = {
    headerToolbar: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: ''
    },
    locale: deLocale,
    initialView: 'listMonth',
    plugins: [listPlugin],
    datesSet: (arg) => { this.initEvents(arg.start, arg.end) },
    eventClick: this.openEditEventDialog.bind(this)
  };

  async initEvents(viewStart: Date, viewEnd: Date): Promise<void> {
    let allCalendarEvents: EventInput[] = [];
    const allEvents = await this.eventService.getAllEventsOfView(viewStart, viewEnd).toPromise();

    for (const event of allEvents) {
      allCalendarEvents.push({
        id: event.id.toString(), title: event.name, start: event.start_timestamp, end: event.end_timestamp, extendedProps: {
          public: event.public,
          gema: event.gema,
          security: event.security,
          external: event.external
        }
      });
    }

    this.calendarOptions.events = allCalendarEvents;
    this.calendarOptions.eventDidMount = (allCalendarEvents) => {
      let publicity = '';
      let gema = '';
      let external = '';
      let security = '';

      if (allCalendarEvents.event.extendedProps.public === true) {
        publicity = ', öffentlich';
      };
      if (allCalendarEvents.event.extendedProps.external === true) {
        external = ', extern';
      };
      if (allCalendarEvents.event.extendedProps.gema === true) {
        gema = ', GEMA gemeldet';
      };
      if (allCalendarEvents.event.extendedProps.security === true) {
        security = ', Security gemeldet';
      };

      let status = publicity + external + gema + security;
      if (status.length > 1) {
        status = status.substring(2);
        allCalendarEvents.el.querySelector('.fc-list-event-title').innerHTML = allCalendarEvents.event.title + ` <i>(${status})</i>`;
      }
    };
  }
```

I also use a modal to edit those booleans, but I am not able to update the title string. It always needs a reload.
This is my current approach:

```
async openEditEventDialog(clickInfo: EventClickArg) {

    const editEvent = await this.eventService.getEventById(+clickInfo.event.id).toPromise();

    const ref = this.matDialog.open<EditEventComponent, EditEventData, EventDto>(EditEventComponent, {
      data: {
        event: editEvent,
      }
    });

    const result = await ref.afterClosed().toPromise();

    if (!!result) {
      try {
          const event = await this.eventService.updateEvent(result).toPromise();
          let publicity = '';
          let gema = '';
          let external = '';
          let security = '';

          if (event.public === true) {
            publicity = ', öffentlich';
          };
          if (event.external === true) {
            external = ', extern';
          };
          if (event.gema === true) {
            gema = ', GEMA gemeldet';
          };
          if (event.security === true) {
            security = ', Security gemeldet';
          };

          let status = publicity + external + gema + security;
          if (status.length > 1) {
            status = status.substring(2);
            clickInfo.event.setProp("title", event.name + " <i>(" + status + ")</i>");
          } else {
            clickInfo.event.setProp("title", event.name);
          }
        }
      } catch (error) {
        this.errorService.showDialog(`Error => Could not edit event: ${error.toString()}`);
      }
  }
```

When I toggle one of those booleans in the EditModal, the plain title gets attached to the current title of all events, like this

title after edit => "Testevent (öffentlich, extern)Testevent"

I want to know how I can refresh just the edited event in view? Regards